# GWT FormPanel onSubmitComplete event not firing when downloading a file

Tags: events, servlets, gwt

I created servlet to download file from a server. In GWT I created a FormPanel and I am able to download a file.

Problem is, that I want to fire an event, when the file is ready. I tried to use onSubmitComplete event, but it isn't firing.

I found a suggestion, to change ContetType to "text/html", but still no luck. I found, that the problem lies in writing to OutputStream - when commented out, event is fired.

Here is my servlet code

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=File.xls");

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    try {

        workbook = fileCreator.getWorkbook();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().print("something");
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

So file is downloaded successfully, but event is not triggered. Even when I just get OutputStream and close it (without writing to it), event stops working.

When I remove whole "writing-to-output-stream" code, event works like a charm.
Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Here is code for FormPanel and its handlers, meby there is a problem?

Form:

```
downloadFileFormPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_URLENCODED);
downloadFileFormPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
panel.setWidth(UIConstatns.SIZE_100percent);
downloadFileFormPanel.setWidget(panel);

downloadFileButton = new Button(messages.EXPORT_LIMITS());
downloadFileButton.setWidth(UIConstatns.SIZE_100percent);
downloadFileButton.addStyleName("navigation-button");
panel.add(downloadFileButton);
```

Handlers

```
private void registerExportLimitsHandler() {
registerHandler(getView().getDownloadFileButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            getView().showLoadingDialog();
            getDownloadFileForm().submit();
        }
    }));
}

private void registerFormSubmitCompleteHandler() {
    getView().getDownloadFileForm().addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {
        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
            Window.alert("download complete");
            getView().hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: onSubmitComplete will only be invoked if the response type is text/html only.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadoc of ServletResponse#getWriter()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) you can either use `response.getOutputStream()` or `response.getWriter()` to write the body of the response, but not both. Furthermore it is better to set the status code of the response before writing the body. Please try the following:

```
// ...
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
workbook.write(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
// response.getWriter().print("something");
// response.flushBuffer();
```

Comment: Still not working. Looks like 'response' doesn't like when messing with its OutputStream. I tried PrintWriter instead, but with the same result unfortunatelly

Comment: do you see any exceptions? maybe it's better to use your own OutputStream for `workbook.write(out)` and then write the content of this outputstream to the response via `out.write()`

Comment: Problem is, there are no exceptions. everything works fine, event just doesn't get triggered. I could try with own OutputStream, but I am afraid it won't help. If simple calling response.getOutputStream() or response.getWriter() without writing to it causes the problem, there must be something else I think. Meby there is a problem, that I am doing this with FormPanel. I could use something else, but don't know where to get event from (successfull request event)

Comment: Oops, then i'm sorry for my misleading answer. I thought, that the  mixing up of `getWriter()` and `getOutputStream()` must be the cause of this problem.

Comment: I updated my question with FormPanel and handlers code. Meby the problem lies somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the line where you create your `FormPanel` so I'm not sure if this was your problem:

Looks like the `FormPanel(String target)` constructor does not work with the `SubmitCompleteHandler`. With the default constructor it seems to work.